# Append Textarea (description) when uploading an image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a basic file upload in Vue.js. I am trying to append a textarea so that I can add a description about the file. However, I can not see to get this to work. The idea is to be able to send files through the API that i am creating in laravel.

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
        Files
        <input type="file" id="files" ref="files" multiple v-on:change="handleFilesUpload()" />
      <div v-for="(file, key) in files" :key="file.id" class="file-listing">
        {{ file.name }}
          <textarea
            name="description"
            id="description"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
            v-model="description"
          ></textarea>
        <span class="remove-file" v-on:click="removeFile( key )">Remove</span>
      </div>
      <button v-on:click="addFiles()">Add Files</button>
      <button v-on:click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      description: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addFiles() {
      this.$refs.files.click();
    },
    submitFiles() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      let description = this.description;
      description = JSON.stringify(description);
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        let file = this.files[i];

        formData.append("files[" + i + "]", file);
        formData.append("description[" + i + "]", description);
      }
      axios
        .post("/media", formData, {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
          }
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log("SUCCESS!!");
        })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log("FAILURE!!");
        });
    },

    handleFilesUpload() {
      let uploadedFiles = this.$refs.files.files;
      for (var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
        this.files.push(uploadedFiles[i]);
      }
    },
    removeFile(key) {
      this.files.splice(key, 1);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I am trying to add a description for each file. Does anyone have any ideas please?

Comment: Are you trying to add a description for each file ? or one for all of them?

Comment: @talkhabi I am adding descriptions to each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there is one description model but we need a description model for each file.
So let define them

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    Files
    <input
      id="files"
      ref="files"
      type="file"
      multiple
      @change="handleFilesUpload()"
    />
    <div v-for="(item, key) in files" :key="key" class="file-listing">
      {{ item.file.name }}
      <textarea
        v-model="item.description"
        name="description"
        cols="30"
        rows="10"
      ></textarea>
      <span class="remove-file" @click="removeFile(key)">Remove</span>
    </div>
    <button @click="addFiles()">Add Files</button>
    <button @click="submitFiles()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
      description: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addFiles() {
      this.$refs.files.click()
    },
    submitFiles() {
      let formData = new FormData()
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        let item = this.files[i]
        formData.append('files[' + i + ']', item.file)
        formData.append('description[' + i + ']', item.description)
      }
      axios
        .post('/media', formData, {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
          }
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log('SUCCESS!!')
        })
        .catch(function() {
          console.log('FAILURE!!')
        })
    },

    handleFilesUpload() {
      let uploadedFiles = this.$refs.files.files
      for (var i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
        this.files.push({
          file: uploadedFiles[i],
          description: ''
        })
      }
    },
    removeFile(key) {
      this.files.splice(key, 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

See working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/talkhabi/fm2pqzgo/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I can see what you have added! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div class="field relative">
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea class="textarea" v-model="description" type="text" maxlength="10000"> </textarea>
        <label for="upload-file" class="icn icn-camera cursor-pointer absolute bottom-3 right-4">
          <input type="file" id="upload-file" hidden ref="file" @change="getImage($event)" accept="image/**" />
        </label>
      </div>
```

1. use Relative and Absolute position to put the camera icon inside the
   textarea
2. use bottom-3 right-4 to find the proper position
3. change the default upload file icon to a camera icon